# How do I measure security in SonarQube 7.0?

Tags: java, security, sonarqube, owasp

I have checked OWASP in SonarQube, but I'm looking for other security metrics to test my proyects in java. I've already checked the Security option in Sonarqube, but it seems to be related to variable names and simple security rules, so maybe there's a security plugin that could help me.

Comment: Maybe you should try a more recent version. [See this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50029819/209452)

Answer (score 0):

[Find Security Bugs](http://find-sec-bugs.github.io/) is the plugin you are looking for.

> [Find Security Bugs](http://find-sec-bugs.github.io/)
>
> The FindBugs plugin for security audits of Java web applications.

According to the authors it provides:

> Extensive references are given for each bug patterns with references to OWASP Top 10 and CWE.